# History of Physics books

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, resource-recommendations, history

I would like some book reference regarding the history of physics. I'm a civil engineering student, and I want to have some basics on the type of developments regarding my field of specialization (structures). For example, I want to look at something and know "No, this can't be it, because this is a physics conception already refuted by ... in ...; what is really going on now is ..etc.". Resuming, history book on physics to give a structural engineer a good insight in the areas he might see through his work. I know I gonna see classical mechanics, because I'm studying a lot of it, but I don't understand why. Didn't Einstein refuted that? I wasn't supposed to be seeing relativity?

Sorry if the question is stupid, I didn't had anywhere else to ask. Have a nice day.

Comment: Could this be merged into a new section of the [book list question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/12175/book-recommendations) maybe?
I think History of Physics books would be another good set to have in the list

Comment: I have nominated this question for deletion because it has no answers and is closed so no new answers can be posted. Nobody has shown any interest in it for 3 years. It serves no useful purpose on the site.